# cross origin for amazon lambda function from localhost in gatsby site

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, cross-domain

I have the following code which works when I run it as a local serverless function with netlify dev, but I need it to run cross origin from a dev server to the hosted server function. I put the function in a aws lambda function but I am getting a cross origin blocked error on my https:dev.website.com, I thought I have the correct headers in the return object so not sure why I am getting a cross origin error.

Any help would be great

```
const sanityClient = require("@sanity/client");
const client = sanityClient({
  projectId: "random-id",
  dataset: "production",
  useCdn: true,
});

exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
  var body = JSON.parse(event.body);

  //console.log(body.price_id)

  try {
    const checkPriceId = async (test) => {
      const query = `*[_type == "products" && price_id == "${body.price_id}"]`;

      const documents = await client.fetch(query, {}); // this could throw

      return documents.map((document) => document.sold);
    };

    var ok = checkPriceId().then((test) => {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        //console.log(test) // this will log the return value from line 7
        console.log(test);
        resolve(test);
      });
    });

    var bools = await ok;
    // prettier-ignore

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET, POST, OPTION',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        sold: bools,
      }),
    };
  } catch (err) {
    return { statusCode: 500, body: err.toString() };
  }
};
```

This is my request to the function if that helps

```
 var fetchUrl = https://random.executue-api.aws.com/prod/sold //not exact 

 var fetchData = async function () {
    const response = await fetch(fetchUrl, {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        price_id: final,
      }),
    })
      .then(res => {
        return res.json()
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))

    return response
  }
```

**Update**:

I tried adding cors the way suggested in the answer below, but it failed seen below so I tried manually adding the method response seen after.

I still get a cross domain error. And I have changed the domain so it is now https as well. Really stuck here.

[image: cors failing]

[image: manual cors addition]

I was looking into this more, and it seems like before it does the actual post it does a cors check at the options method, so I added in the same access control headers, and deployed but did not work. Don't quite get this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your headers look ok to me. (note: If you mix HTTP and HTTPS you are most likely to get a mixed content error in the client). If it is ONLY a CORS issue that you are seeing in the console in the web browser, then you might not have configured the API Gateway correctly in AWS.

In AWS, go to *API Gateway* and you should see something like the below:
[image]

Make sure that you enable CORS and then redeploy.

UPDATE:
Just looking at a previous implementation of a lambda function I setup with AWS. The headers I declared were as follows:

```js
headers: {        
  "Content-Type" : "application/json",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
  "Allow" : "GET, OPTIONS, POST",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "GET, OPTIONS, POST",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "*",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true
}
```

Your headers look OK to me though. However, when you created the method in the API Gateway, did you select *Use Proxy Lambda Integration*? (see screenshot).

[image]

Your client side fetch request looks ok. For reference mine was:

```
const url = 'your url';
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
};
fetch(url, options).then(res => res.json());
```

Unrelated to this issue, but its not advisable to mix Async/Await with .then promise chaining. But this isn't the issue you are having. Just something to note.

Comment: I attempted your suggestion but it failed, I posted an update above

Comment: I have updated my answer, let me know if it helps.

Comment: I noticed in my code, I had written OPTION instead of OPTIONS but that change still hasn't worked. And I have use lambda as proxy checked. I even tried copying and pasting you headers, so I am so lost here. Thanks for your help thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Check the **values** from your ***Integration Response*** / try setting them manually for both OPTIONS ***and*** POST (and if that works, make sure you are passing through the response correctly from the lambda).

Your POST action should only require the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.  The other two (Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Headers) belong in the OPTION action. See this writeup, and note the full example exchange for a preflighted request (in grey): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests

[image: Integration to Response Mapping]

[image]